# get file path & file name value from right click windows, c#

Tags: c#

I have my own application and I want to add it to right click menu on Windows by defining command on key registry such `C://myapp.exe "%1"`

My problem is I want to get file name and path from file I choosed by clicking the right click menu and passing the value to visual studio C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string c = "thefilepath&filename"
}
```

How do i get the value to fill string?

pardon me for my english..
tq

Answer (score 0):

The value should be in the `args` array of the main method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get your application executed from right-click in windows explorer then windows shell should be passing you the file path. Try this:

```
if(args.Length>0)
{
    string c = args[0];
    /NOW USE c
}
```

Comment: i use

if(args.Length>0)
{
    string c = args[0];
    Image img = Image.FromFile(c);
}

i got this error message : 
Illegal characters in path.
value of c = " \"C:\\a.JPG\""

Comment: actually the path provided is already in double quotes that is why you have `\"` before **C**. Try removing any double quotes from string like this: `string c=args[0].Replace("\"","");`